# Could not load file or assembly ... after changing the TargetingFramework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, frameworks, nuget, .net-standard

I just changed the .csproj from `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>` to     `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` and when debugging, I receive the following:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '..., Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified. at CDMToJSON.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I tried adding all missing .dll's in the folder (`Sources\CDMToJSON\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0`), but for one with the `Newtonsoft.Json` the error kept persisting, which made me think that there would be a better way to add these NuGets and dependencies.

Therefore, how can I add all these .dll's properly after changing the Targeting Framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`netstandard` TFMs are only for libraries. They cannot be used for projects which are directly executable, such as desktop apps, console apps, or unit test projects.

You need to pick a concrete runtime that your program will target, such as `netcoreapp3.1` or `net5.0`, and then target it.